# Can EF Core be configured to ignore a child property when saving, create the relationship with a foreign key, but still populate child on retrieval?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core

I have a parent object that sets a child property with its foreign key to prevent duplication of the child in the database.

```
public class Unit
{
   public Unit(UnitType unitType)
   {
      unitTypeCode = unitType.Id;
   }

   public UnitType UnitType {get; private set;}
   private int unitTypeCode;
}

public class UnitType
{
    public static UnitType  Campus => new UnitType(1, nameof(Campus));
    private UnitType(int id, string name)
    { ... }
    public int Id {get; private set;}
    public string Name {get;private set;}
}
```

This is sufficient for the application as the unit will always be retrieved through the `DbContext` before any further operations are done on it. The issue is when writing unit tests for this object, I am not using EF Core to test which is resulting in my `UnitType` property not being set.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Can_Set_Campus()
{
     var unit = new Unit(UnitType.Campus);

     // this will be false because unit.UnitType is never set
     Assert.IsTrue(unit.UnitType == UnitType.Campus); 
}
```

Is there a way to set the `UnitType` and have EF Core ignore it when saving (using the foreign key to create the relationship) but still populate the related property when retrieving the data?

Alternatively, is there a better way to handle testing for this type of situation?

Update:
more info on UnitType structure per Felipe's comment: There are 3 'UnitTypes' that can be assigned to a Unit:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Campus |
| 2 | Building |
| 3 | Room |

I am creating a new object each time, which is why I am using the foreign key to create the relationship in EF Core (to avoid creating the duplicate that EF by default creates when the object is populated). Ultimately is there a way to tell EF "Don't create a record for the UnitType when saving, just add the _unitTypeId for foreign key reference"?

I know I could retrieve the UnitType from the DB every time, so it's already being tracked by EF, but  I would prefer to not to have to do this. I'd like to keep only aggregate roots exposed in the DbContext.

We are managing status indicators in a similar way, so this issue manifests itself in multiple ways.

Comment: There should be more to Unit if it has a foreign key to UnitType. Usualy you will have the actual foreign key, for example UnitTypeId, and the foreign key object for example UnitType. In the test you could compare UnitTypeId==1. I think more information on the underlying sql structure might help to better understand your use case and question to provide a better answer.

Comment: Wouldn't that assertion fail because `Campus` is not a singleton? You seem to be creating a new object every time you get the property.